# Getting INVALID_COUNTRY_CODE exception when trying to parse phone number without country code

Tags: libphonenumber

I am using libphonenumber jar (version 7) and trying to parse phone number without setting Region. I saw following code as recommended.

```
PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse(numberStr, ""));
```

However, this is throwing INVALID_COUNTRY_CODE exception. Did something change in the latest version? How can I get region code (US) for given number like ("+1-xxx-xxx-xxxx")?

Answer (score 1):

I used libphonenumber 7.0.8 and it worked:

```java
public static void main(final String[] args) {
  String numberStr = "+1 650-253-0000"; // Google
  PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
  PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder geocoder = PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder.getInstance();
  try {
    PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse(numberStr, null);
    System.out.println(geocoder.getDescriptionForNumber(phoneNumber, Locale.ENGLISH));
  } catch (NumberParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

It worked using:

- `phoneUtil.parse(numberStr, null);`
- `phoneUtil.parse(numberStr, "");`
- `phoneUtil.parse(numberStr, "ZZ");`

Output is always `Mountain View, CA` - so the number was parsed successfully.

From the [javadoc](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn@628/trunk/javadoc/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) you can find this information:

> If the number is guaranteed to start with a '+' followed by the country calling code, then "ZZ" or null can be supplied.